# auto updating elements on page with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page on which a news slider views items held one by one. The page automatically gets new items on refresh.

I'm trying to use ajax and a jquery timer to automatically update the page when a new item is added, to do this I'm attempting to call the current page again via AJAX and compare the children inside the news slider's wrapping div. however I cant get the data from the page in the first place.

the code i am currently using is:

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: ctx.HttpRoot,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            var stripped_data = $(data).find("div#newsSliderWrapper");
            //Code here will put the AJAX copy of #newsSliderWrapper into the current pages #newsSliderWrapper
        },
        error: function () {
            // your error logic
            alert("AJAX failed");
        }
    })
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console to see if there are any errors in getting the data?

Comment: no errors at all. Its returning it in a weird fashion, rather than HTML

Comment: What kind of "weird fashion"?

Comment: well, im assuming its JSON. $(data) returns jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[145]
[0 … 99]
[100 … 144]
context: undefined
length: 145
selector: ""
__proto__: Object[0]


and body return something that i cannot use find on

Comment: If you run ctx.HttpRoot on its own, does it display HTML? If not, you'll need to go about this a different way.

Comment: ctx.HttpRoot is a Url to a sharepoint page

Comment: Have you considered using load() then? $('#newsSliderWrapper').load(ctx.HttpRoot, '#newsSliderWrapper'); http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I have tried it, yes. For some reason it send the whole page white and only displays a h2 for the whole page. odd

Comment: All AJAX requests get the whole page, load() just narrows down what is displayed as it has the logic that you propose to put into your function. Have you checked the markup of the Sharepoint page to make sure it is what you would expect it to be?

Comment: its the same page im calling it from. I think the problem lies with passing the HttpRoot with a comma in the .load function. EDIT: however, that being said. passing the url as a string just resets the wrapper div to a white.... annoying as hell

Comment: Is there a URL you can use?

Answer (score 0):

```
var stripped_data = $(data).find("div#newsSliderWrapper");
```

This line will try to invoke function fund of data obtained from the AJAX call. Not sure if this is what you want as find applies to DOM object and the current data is raw data, not even dummy DOM.

If the obtained data is HTML element, then you must do following first

```
var dataDom = $(data);
```

This make convert data to dummy data and now you can perform `.find` on it.